# Integrating vector fields over a surface

Tags: calculus

Let our surface be $S=\{(x,y,z)| x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z\ge 0\}$ and our vector field be $F=(z^2,x,y^2)$. Verify Stokes Theorem. $\int \int_S \nabla \times F  ds= \int_{\delta S} F ds$

I have calculated $\nabla \times F=(2y,2z,1)$ but am now stuck on what to do. I don't understand how to set up the bounds for either integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

For the line integral, the boundary of the surface is when $z=0$.  In this case, your line integral is over the unit circle.  So, you should use the parameterization 
$$
\vec{r}(t)=\cos(t)\vec{i}+\sin(t)\vec{j}
$$
for $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$.

For the surface integral, you could write $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ and then integrate over the unit disk.  In this case, I would convert to polar coordinates to make everything easier.